# What is minimal dependency import for location.places?

Tags: android, google-play-services

I follow this [example](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-places/tree/master/PlaceCompleteAdapter) to make places aotu complete adapter. In example whole place-services library is imported and its seems to be excessive.
I imported

```
  compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:9.6.1'
  compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.6.1'
```

However `com.google.android.gms.location.places.AutocompleteFilter` is not present in any of the above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must include the `dependency` for `places APIs`.

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:9.6.1';
```

The `places` dependency was only added in `Google Play services 9.2.0` - before that, it was part of the`maps` dependency, which was a requirement for `location` (`version 9.6.0` also removed the dependency of `location` on `maps`), hence why previously when you included `location` you also got `places`.